# Displaying details based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

```
$scope.units.push({
  id: response[j]["productId"],
  itemPrice: response[j].productPrice,
  discountPrice: response[j].discountPrice,
  productUnit: response[j].productUnit
});
```

I have units array. It contains id, itemprice..fields with data. 
I am displaying radio buttons based on productunits.
(I mean number of productunit is equal to number of radio buttons). If i select radio button then i want to display specific itemprice, discountprice.
how to achieve it?

Comment: how are displaying the radio buttons?

Comment: <p ng-repeat="item in units ">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="item" ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-click="getValues(item)" value="item"/>
            {{item.productUnit}}
          </label>
        </p>

Comment: update the same to post. and make your question more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are assigning the selected item to a scope variable called `selectedPerson` through `ng-model`. Thus, you can simply print the data outside the `ng-repeat` scope. Something like:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in units ">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="item" ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-value="item"/>
        {{item.productUnit}}
    </label>
</p>
<p>{{selectedPerson.itemPrice}} {{selectedPerson.discountPrice}}</p>
```

**IMPORTANT:** don't forget to initialize `$scope.selectedPerson = {}` in your controller so that `selectedPerson` belongs to your controller's scope instead of `ng-repeat`'s scope.

Comment: Thanks for quick response lucasnadalutti. I will try this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add something to the `input`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks lucasnadalutti. i will try